# What is the meaning of 店頭分?

Tags: meaning, nouns, compounds

I visited a shopping website, and I read 予約を含め在庫がなくなった場合、店頭分をご用意できない場合がございますことを予めご了承ください。I couldn't understand 店頭分 properly. What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

店頭 means "store front" and 店頭分 means " items which is sold in a shop".

Comment: 分 means "part/portion". 店頭"分" was used because the shop owner had the whole stock in their mind, and was thinking how much of it they could allocate to the real shop.